# Combining Month-Year Columns for for Loops Purpose

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a data frame:

```
df =

yr    mth    data1
1990    9         20
1990    9         30
1990    10        40
1990    11        50
1990    12        90
1991    1         80
1991    1        100
1991    2         75
```

I want to calculate the sum of data1 for every 2 months as per below:

```
result = [90,90,140,270,175]
```

where 90  is sum of data1 for year 1990 month 9 & 10 as well as sum of data1 for year 1990 month 10 & 11, 140 sum of data1 for year 1990 month 11 & 12, 270 is sum of data 1 for year 1990 month 12 and year 1991 month 1.
I can do this one by one, for example for year 1990 month 9 & 10:

```
df_ = df.loc[(df.yr == 1990) & (df.mth.isin([9,10]))]

df_.data1.sum()
```

But if the data frame is large, I more efficient way (for loops or any other way), but for for loops I am not sure how to do this since I need to combine column yy_mth as year-month.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're already familiar with the vectorized operations of PANDAS; this is good.

- Form a new column, making a datetime form the existing year and month.
- Use `groupby` and `sum` to make a frame with the totals for each month.
- Use a rolling window of two months (see any referend on "moving" or "rolling" windows in PANDAS) to get your two-month totals.

Perhaps even easier than the third step would be to use `shift(1)` to give you another series of months, one row displaced.  Then simply add that series to the original, and you have a new series of two-month totals.

Given what you posted already, I trust that you can do the coding details.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ { "yr": 1990, "mth": 9, "data1": 20 }, { "yr": 1990, "mth": 9, "data1": 30 }, { "yr": 1990, "mth": 10, "data1": 40 }, { "yr": 1990, "mth": 11, "data1": 50 }, { "yr": 1990, "mth": 12, "data1": 90 }, { "yr": 1991, "mth": 1, "data1": 80 }, { "yr": 1991, "mth": 1, "data1": 100 }, { "yr": 1991, "mth": 2, "data1": 75 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.groupby((df['mth'].shift() != df['mth']).cumsum(), as_index=False)['data1'].sum() # use groupby to group by months, get sum of data1 values
df.rolling(2).sum().dropna()['data1'].astype(int).tolist() #create rolling window with sum of two months, drop NaNs, create list
```

Result:

```
[90, 90, 140, 270, 255]
```